# Pyinstaller and PyQt5 macOS Mojave compatibility issues

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, macos-mojave

My application, created with Pyinstaller, worked fine until I upgraded from High Sierra to Mojave. In order to demonstrate the issue I create the simple application. 
Main window has only one button. When you press the button its text should be changed to "Please wait" for 10 seconds. 
When I run this program as .py script, everything works fine, but after creating .app file with Pyinstaller it behaves differently. The text is not updated until you click anywhere outside of the window.

I tried to reinstall Pyinstaller, but the problem still exists.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(303, 304)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 300, 43))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 170, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setDefault(True)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.pushButton.setEnabled(True))


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click me"))


    def click(self):
        if not self.thread.isRunning():
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.pushButton.setText("Please wait")
            self.label.setText("The button below should display \n 'Please wait' for 10 seconds")
            self.thread.start()

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):

        time.sleep(10)
        ui.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        ui.pushButton.setText("Click me") 
        ui.label.setText("")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I guess the issue is not in my code but in Mojave and Pyinstaller compatibility. Please let me know if it works for you.

BTW you marked it as duplicate and linked it to MultyThead PyQt question. I think it's wrong, because it's completely different issue.

Comment: I have not tested it on Mac OS, I'm going to reopen the question. I closed it because your current implementation is incorrect: you should not update the GUI from another thread, maybe Windows allows it sometimes but Qt does not guarantee that it works, instead use signals as you point out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. In order to solve this rendering issue you need to add the following line for a ui element, which needs to be updated. In my case it is required only if I need to run this application on macOS Mojave.

`<element>.repaint()`

For example:

```
def click(self):             
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton.setText("Button is clicked...")
        self.pushButton.repaint()
```